# I would like to have the limits of a sum right to the sum symbol (like in inline mode) inside an equation environment

Tags: math-mode

I have sums inside an equation environment and I would like to have the limits right to the sum (like in inline equations), not below and above. What do I need to do?

Comment: `\sum\nolimits_0^n`

Comment: For a single occurrence or always?

Comment: @campa Right now David Carlisle's answer for a single occurrence suffices, but for the future it might be helpful to know what to do if I want it always :)

Comment: You can use `{\textstyle \sum_0^n}` to make it precisely like inline math.

Comment: For all limits on all operator (integrals excluded) `\usepackage[nosumlimits]{amsmath}`

Comment: @JohnKormylo Careful: that changes the math operator to an ordinary symbol, thus ruining spacing.